# Poor MySQL performance after upgrade

Tags: mysql, xampp, database-performance

Applications in our company were working on quite old Apache + MySQL bundle (with PHP 5.x) but they were fast in retrieving data from the database. Simple retrieval of around 100 rows with some basic calculations would take around a second or two.

We had that bundle upgraded to the newest XAMPP version and all features it comes with. Applications were not changed (they did not have to, they just retrieve data and calculate them) but the performance of the very same operations has lowered significantly, they take around 20 seconds, sometimes up to 50 seconds.

I would appreciate it if anybody could point me to what can be done to improve the performance on that new bundle.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It might be more useful to ask this in the XAMPP topic.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone ever experiences this error, your my.ini needs some improvements on the size of cache and buffer. There's a working version of my.ini available if you search it on Google. It worked like a miracle in terms of MySQL performance.

Comment: `innodb_buffer_pool_size` should be set to about 70% of _available_ RAM.